# Get the name of the current database from Heroku via command line

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Is there a command that gets the name of the current Postgres in a Heroku application?
I am writing a batch file that should be used in multiple stages of my application. Each time the only difference is the name of the database.
Using heroku pg, I could retrieve the complete URL of the database:

```
heroku pg:credentials:url DATABASE
```

Maybe I could extract the name from the URL using some Linux tools, but in the context of batch files, I prefer not to use anything but Heroku tools to keep environment independency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't provide a parsed version of `$DATABASE_URL` (which you can also get with `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL`. If you need the database name, you'll need to parse it yourself or use a tool to do so.